# How to write the output into a file Using Storm

Tags: apache-storm, filereader, filewriter

Hi I created a Storm Program which reads a text file `input.txt` using the spout class line by line and emits those tuples to bolt, In bolt class I want to write the tuples into  `output.txt`. I had almost done but the problem is the storm writes many times in the output file. Look at my `input.txt`and  `output.txt` file

Input.txt

```
Kaveen,bigdata,29
varadha,cshart,30
vignesh,winrt,21
```

Output.

```
varadha,cshart,30
vignesh,winrt,21
Kaveen,bigdata,29
varadha,cshart,30
Kaveen,bigdata,29
Kaveen,bigdata,29
vignesh,winrt,21
```

I want to write the output file exactly as similar to inputfile but the order isn't a matter. How do I achieve that please help me.

Comment: you'll need to provide more detail around how you're topology is structured. Also, straight out writing to an output file might not behave the way you want it to if you put this topology on an actual storm install, the output file would get written on each of the supervisor machines.

Comment: could you please post the code you are using to create the topology,curious to see what is the level of parallelism set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same problem, so found following solution for that.

In Spout, when you are reading file, create **FileReader object** in **open()** method,because that time it initiatizes the reader object for worker node.
And use that object in nextTuple() method.
**(*with one spout and one bolt*)**

Following is the code for open() and nextTuple method:

```
    public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context,
            SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
            try {
            this.context = context;
            File file = new File(filename);
            this.fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error reading file ["+ filename + "]");
        }
        this.collector = collector;
    }

    public void nextTuple() {
        /**
         * The nextuple it is called forever, so if we have been readed the file
         * we will wait and then return
         */
        if (completed) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Do nothing
            }
            return;
        }
        String str;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        try {
            // Read all lines
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                /**
                 * By each line emit a new value with the line as a their
                 */
                this.collector.emit(new Values(str), str);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error reading tuple", e);
        } finally {
            completed = true;
        }
    }
```

Output  :

```
Kaveen,bigdata,29
varadha,cshart,30
vignesh,winrt,21
```

**Another issue can be :**

You may be running more than one instance for spout, that can cause repetitive emission of streams, or file is written in append mode.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing the content to the `output.txt` file, just open the `output.txt` in append mode. whenever a write statement occurs just append the content to this `output.txt` there by checking the duplicate records in the file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have more than one spout instance reading the input file causing duplicate records in the output.